# jQuery Mobile Collapsible set, How to check if a div element is expanded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set that contain two blocks:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
        <h3>Block A</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Block B</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

And I want to know which block is expanded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy. jQuery Mobile does all of this using CSS. When a `collapsible` UI element is collapsed, the class "**`ui-collapsible-collapsed`**" is added to that element. So all you have to do is use the *`.hasClass()`* method of `jQuery` on that specific `collapsible`.

For example, here is some HTML:

```html
...
<div id="blocks" data-role="collapsible-set">
    <div class="block" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
        <h3>Block A</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="block" data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Block B</h3>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

And here is some example JavaScript/jQuery:

```js
...
if ($('#blocks .block').hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
    // Do whatever you want to do here.
}
...
```